# ExtJs NumberField Using thousand seperator

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

there is an old project that uses ExtJs 3.0 and i need to use number field with thousand seperator and currency (USD, EUR, TL etc.). But when i sent/get it to/from server with ajax request the original value must be post/get. ExtJs 3.0 number field does not support too much options. Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how to show number field as currency on UI only, right? If that, try using `Ext.util.Format` on your renderer.
Something like this below code:

```
id: 'abc',
header: 'ABC'
renderer: function(value){
    return Ext.util.Format.usMoney(value);
}
```

I have not found ExtJS 3.0 Documents, but in [Extjs3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-usMoney) I found that the `Ext.util.Format` is available from version 1.1.

Comment: Hey hienvd, thank you for your answer. But it didnt help too much.

Comment: <code>var money = new Ext.form.NumberField({
 fieldLabel : 'Money,
 allowBlank : false,
 width : ekranStandartlari.inputWidth,
 labelStyle: 'padding-left:2em;',
 renderer: function(value){
     return Ext.util.Format.usMoney(value);
 }
});</code>